# "Failed to store screenshot"

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm taking a screenshot using `"ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot (pathToSave)" and it's works great in unity, that my code:

```
string timeStemp = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss");
string fileName = "Screenshoot" + timeStemp + ".png";    
string pathToSave = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + fileName;
```

But when I build the game and run it on Android it's not working.
Using "Android devise monitor" I can see the following error:
[image]

any idea's on how to solve the issue?

Comment: Are you out of storage space?

Comment: Have you requested the permission storage of android ?

Comment: The file is a "png", its in the code "string fileName = "Screenshoot" + timeStemp + ".png"; and in Unity I can see the files I have created, a health Png files. And I got allot of free storage on my mobile.

Comment: It seems that the path in your filename is doubled. Can you provide a more complete code snippet?

Comment: Does it work if you set `fileName` to `a.png` (as a temporary test)?

Answer (score 1):

Is this a permission issue (because you can see the error says it couldn't STORE it, not take it) ? Or maybe you can try to change the output directory (it is pretty weird to put it in the app's folder)

Request storage permission (note that you might want to request the access to the user above android 6.0)

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

You can also check for space

```
/* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */
public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
        Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I checked for the permission live in manifest file and it's exist, I copied it into Plugins/Android  just to be sure and still "“Failed to store screenshot", for the space check , do you have it or can direct me to a C# example?

Comment: @DrorDavidovich Sorry I don't have a C# version of this code but it should be pretty easy to translate, use InteliSense to find the correct references. For instance "getExternalStorage" become ".ExternalStorage". 
You should also check your android version, if you are above 6.0 adding the permission to the manifest isn't enough, you have to request it (see reference here : https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

Comment: Thanks, I will try to learn about the runtime permissions and will update you all how things are working out.

Answer (score 0):

just want to close the issue (better late then never).
I used the following free "Asset store" plugin : [https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/android-runtime-permissions-117803][1]

It's had all I needed in a vary simple code (checking for permissions and asking for them), at first it didn't work, after chatting with the vary nice guy who wrote the code, we discover that deleting the:"android:maxSdkVersion="18"" at the end of the permission line in the manifest made it work. So now I can ask for permissions. Thank you all!